# Function with Optional parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to learn and implement a Function in VBA with an optional argument. I am trying to seperate values in a string given a character or substring to seperate.

```
Private Function SeperateString(MainString As String, Seperator As String) As String
{

 // Body 

}
```

Eg: I want to seperate "1-2-3-4-5" using seperator "-" or "1/2/3/4/5" using seperator "/".

I will write the logic using Instr and other functions. My doubt is I want to pass a seperator so I don't need to write a seperate function for each and want "-" to be default if nothing is passed. Can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming, you want to set `Separator` as optional parameter, try this:

```
Private Function SeperateString(MainString As String, _
           Optional Seperator As String = "-") As String

 'Body 
     SeperateString = "result of function"
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
result = SeperateString("whatever-it-is") 'uses default separator
result = SeperateString("whatever-it-is", "*") 'uses another separator
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
Private Function SeparateString(MainString as String, 
                                Optional Separator as String = "-") As String
```

Oh, and this is VBA. No `{}` and no `//`, but I'm sure you know that...

I would have to suggest, however, that using `Split()` would likely be a better option than writing your own.

Comment: ++ For beating me to it :)

Answer (score 4):

You are working in VBA and not C# so do away with those curly braces.

The moment you type the first line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the VBE will automatically add `End Function`

```
Private Function SeperateString(MainString As String, Seperator As String) As String

End Function
```

To make a parameter optional, use the keyword `Optional` before it

Example

```
Private Function SeperateString(MainString As String, Optional Seperator As String = "-") As String

End Function
```